# Haskell find indices of String in String

Tags: string, haskell, find, substring

I'm currently trying to find the indices of a particular string in another string.
So e.g. the result for string `"ab"` in `"ababa baab ab bla ab"` should be 11 and 18. 
If currently have the problem that with my function I also get the index 0 and 8
My function:

```
findSubstringIndices :: String -> String -> [Int]
findSubstringIndices text pattern = map (add 1) (findIndices (pattern `isPrefixOf`) (tails text))
```

Comment: The first index you should get, given your specification, is 0.

Comment: @larsmanns you're right, I edited my question

Comment: So you're actually looking for the String " ab", not "ab". Note the space

Comment: Also, you get a 2. I'm guessing that you are interesting in word extraction?

Comment: @MrBones, no because than I don't get something like "ab bla"

Comment: Please rewrite the question accordingly and give examples of input and desired outputs.

Answer (score 6):

Picking the right equipment is important here.

```
import Data.Char
```

You could use a slightly modified version of the function `words` from the Prelude, which is defined as:

```
words :: String -> [String]
words s = case dropWhile isSpace s of
  "" -> []
  s' -> w : words s'' where (w, s'') = break isSpace s'
```

It breaks a string up into a list of space-delimited words. The modification would amount to labelling each word with its index into the string. For example:

```
words' :: String -> [(Int, String)]
words' = go 0
  where
    go n s = case break (not . isSpace) s of
      (_, "")  -> []
      (ws, s') -> (n', w) : go (n' + length w) s''
                     where
                       n'       = n + length ws
                       (w, s'') = break isSpace s'
```

For example:

```
> words' "ababa baab ab bla ab"
[(0,"ababa"),(6,"baab"),(11,"ab"),(14,"bla"),(18,"ab")]
```

Now, writing your function `findSubstringIndices` becomes almost trivial:

```
findSubstringIndices :: String -> String -> [Int]
findSubstringIndices text pattern = [i | (i, w) <- words' text, w == pattern]
```

Does it work? Yes, it does:

```
> findSubstringIndices "ababa baab ab bla ab" "ab"
[11,18]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
findWordIndices' :: String -> String -> [Int]
findWordIndices' w = snd . foldl doStuff (0, []) . words
  where
    doStuff (cur, results) word =
        if word == w 
        then (cur + length word + 1, cur : results) 
        else (cur + length word + 1, results)
```

This returns the indices in reverse order, however.

```
g>let str = "ababa baab ab bla ab"
str :: [Char]
g>findWordIndices' "ab" str
[18,11]
it :: [Int]
```

This can be fixed by using `(++)` instead of cons (`(:)`).

```
findWordIndices'' :: String -> String -> [Int]
findWordIndices'' w = snd . foldl doStuff (0, []) . words
  where
    doStuff (cur, results) word =
        if word == w 
        then (cur + length word + 1, results ++ [cur]) 
        else (cur + length word + 1, results)

g>let str = "ababa baab ab bla ab"
str :: [Char]
g>findWordIndices'' "ab" str
[11,18]
it :: [Int]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of `words`:

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Arrow

words' s = 
  case dropWhile isSpace' s of
    [] -> []
    s' -> ((head >>> snd) &&& map fst) w : words' s'' 
          where (w, s'') = break isSpace' s'
  where isSpace' = fst >>> isSpace

indices text pattern =
  map fst $ filter (snd >>> ((==) pattern)) $ words' $ zip text [0..]

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ indices "ababa baab ab bla ab" "ab"
```